# Android: Passing string containing HTML between activities?

Tags: android, android-intent, extras

I'm trying to pass a string between 2 activities using an intent extras bundle.

Parent activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Advice.this, AdviceDetail.class);
Bundle bAdvice = new Bundle();
bAdvice.putString("description", description);
i.putExtras(bAdvice);
startActivity(i);
```

Child activity:

```
Bundle bAdviceDetails = getIntent().getExtras();
String description = bAdviceDetails.getString("description");
```

However, any HTML is always stripped out of my string! Why? How do I work around this?? I've tried using a charArray; same thing happens.

Comment: Try sending it as a byte array. That might help you.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I didn't realise actually was using **Html.fromHtml** before adding to the bundle. Converting this to a string must remove the html tags.